# ImportError: Failed to import test module On Python integration test

Tags: python, python-3.x, integration-testing, python-import, python-unittest

The directory structure of my project looks like this:

```
project/
│
├── __init__.py
├── my_only_script.py
│ 
│
└── tests/
    |
    └── unit/
    |   ├── __init__.py
    |   └── unit_test.py
    |
    └── integration/
        |
        ├── fixtures/
        |   ├── correct_data.csv
        |   └── generated_data.csv
        |
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_integration.py
```

And I'm trying to execute my integration tests for my_only_script.py by running `unittest` in discover mode on the tests directory

```
# working directory is project root 
python -m unittest discover -s tests
```

However, when I run this command, I'm met with the error

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: integration.test_integration
```

Why is it that `unittest` could discover the integration test -- after all, it mentioned the module by name as `integration.test_integration`, so it must have found it -- but still, the integration test could not be imported?

---

**edit**

The full error message I encounter is

```
(base) [project]$ python -m unittest discover -s tests
E
======================================================================
ERROR: integration.test_integration (unittest.loader._FailedTest)

ImportError: Failed to import test module: integration.test_integration
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/david/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
File "/home/david/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
import(name)
File "/home/david/project/tests/integration/test_integration.py", line 13
class PROJECT_INTEGRATION_TEST(unittest.TestCase)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

In test_integration.py, I have tried a relative import `from ... import my_only_script`, an absolute import `from project import my_only_script`, in addition to the plain-old `import my_only_script`. I've also tried commenting out the import statement entirely. All seem to result in the same error shown above.

I know there's nothing *else* wrong with the code in `test_integration.py`, because if I move it into the root of the project directory, and run it using `python test_integration.py` where test_integration.py uses `import my_only_script` the test runs without issue.

Comment: I would guess that some of the imports in `test_integration` failed (maybe due to absolute/relative import problems).

Comment: Ohhh, I see. I thought it was a problem with the directory structure. So what might be the correct way to import `my_only_script.py` from within `test_integration.py`?

Comment: use absolute import from your project root - how it is done now?

Comment: The import statement I have in test_integration.py is just `import my_only_script`, which I thought was right, since it's not in a package, just at the root directory.

Comment: If `project` is your root, you probably need  `from project import my_only_script`

Comment: Weird, I tried that change just now and the import error still showed up. The only other imports I'm making in the integration_test.py are `unittest`,`os`,`fnmatch`, `filecmp`,`json`,`re`, and `pathlib`. Which are all part of the python std library.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong, and there is another problem... try to comment out the import and the test and check if the error still occurs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210318/discussion-between-david-and-mrbean-bremen).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually very simple; I left a colon off the end of

```
class PROJECT_INTEGRATION_TEST(unittest.TestCase) # <- no colon
```

in test_integration.py After fixing that, importing with `import my_only_script` in test_integration.py worked just fine.